# Why doesn't the class name get updated in the DOM when using addClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm following the Javascript & jQuery book by Jon Duckett. In it, I'm trying to recreate [this example project](http://javascriptbook.com/code/c07/example.html).

The bit that's not working is this: (my code)

Func. to update counter:

```
var updateCounter = function(){
  var itemCount = $('ul li[class!=complete]').length;
  $('#counter').text(itemCount);
}
updateCounter();
```

Func. to check if item is complete:

```
var comp = function(){
  var clickedItem = $(this)
  if(clickedItem.hasClass('complete')){
    clickedItem.animate({
      opacity: 0.0
    }, 500, 'swing', function(){
      clickedItem.remove();
    });
  }
  else{
    $(this).addClass('complete');
    var removedItem = $(this).clone();
    $(this).remove();
    list.append(removedItem); 
  }
  updateCounter();
}
```

Func. to add new item:

```
var addNewItem = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var firstComplete = $('ul>.complete').first();
  var newItem = $('#itemDescription:input:text').val();
  if (firstComplete.length !==0){
    firstComplete.before('<li>' + newItem + '</li>');
    hideFormControls();
  }
  else{
    list.append('<li>' + newItem + '</li>');
    hideFormControls();
  }
  updateCounter();
}
```

The difference between my way, and the book, is that when adding a new item to the list, the book types out

```
list.append('<li class=\"complete\">' + newItem + '</li>')
```

whereas, I use addClass. And doing that doesn't update the counter (it does, but it's off by one). I tried adding an event handler to the list:

```
$('ul').on('DOMSubtreeModified', updateCounter);
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not update correctly because you are counting the elements before it is removed. The animation is asynchronous.

```
clickedItem.animate({  //this is asynchronous
    opacity: 0.0
  }, 500, 'swing', function(){ //this is called after updateCounter() was called
    clickedItem.remove();
    updateCounter();  //count after it is removed
  });
```

Comment: It still only updates once I remove the item. With the first click, it'll add the 'complete' class name to the clicked item. On the second click, it'll remove the item. The counter now updates on removal, but ideally, it should update on the first click (once it has the new class name).